# "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host" error when running 'yay'

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pgp

I'm fairly new to Arch Linux, and trying to update my packages. I'm running the latest version of Antergos.

Using `yay` with no arguments, it mostly goes well, up until this:

`==> PGP keys need importing:
 -> 474E22316ABF4785A88C6E8EA2C794A986419D8A, required by: libc++ (libc++abi libc++)
==> Import? [Y/n] 
:: Importing keys with gpg......
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host
==> Error: Problem importing keys`

After hours of searching, all I really found as a fix was to switch to Google DNS. However, after trying both Google and Cloudflare, it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I just observed the same issue. The answer from @eschwartz showed that on my PC the PGP keyserver was reached via its IPv6. I have no idea why, and I never had any IPv6 scope global.

The solution for me was to get the needed keys from another keyserver, like this:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys iNsErThErEtHeFiNgErPrInToFtHeKeYyOuNeEd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `gpg-connect-agent --dirmngr 'keyserver --hosttable' /bye` to inspect the current pool of keyservers you are using. You'll presumably discover that you cannot actually ping the keyserver you're trying to reach.

The most likely cause is network configuration issues, e.g. GnuPG may think you have a (partially configured) IPv6 connection which is actually broken, and prefers using that.

Then change your keyserver to one which you can connect to.

Comment: didn't help me, the trace completes just fine

Comment: This trace helped me get the IPv4 address of the servers and I could use that IP `185.125.188.27 (keyserver.ubuntu.com)` directly as the keyserver argument, `--keyserver 185.125.188.27`.